# Yfinance doesen't download the full price histoy

Tags: python, yfinance

I'm running the exact same code on two different computers. I'm using Yfinance to download stock/index price history. The target is to download the whole history available in Yahoo finance.
The code which I use follows, where I use the option Max. The issue is that on one computer it works and downloads the data starting from 1928 while on the second computer downloads the data starting from 1950. Now I have no idea why and how to fix this behavior. Any idea?

Thanks in advance for your support
Luca

```
 # Get historical market data
    Stock = yf.Ticker(ticker)
    if PeriodType == 'Defined':
        Stock_Data = Stock.history(start=StartDate_Text, end=EndDate_Text,auto_adjust = False)
    elif PeriodType == 'Max':
        Stock_Data = Stock.history(period="max",auto_adjust = False)
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: It seems there is a bug in source code of library. Setting period to "max" causing setting `{`period1': -631159200}` here https://github.com/ranaroussi/yfinance/blob/9eef951acc70121e65825ad25e7afd2edd4c3e4b/yfinance/base.py#L160 However official docs https://www.yahoofinanceapi.com/ for `/v8/finance/chart/{ticker}` endpoint doesn't have such param to accept

Comment: I'm not sure with all this information. It's hard to comment without the ticker, start date, end date, and environmentally, python, yfinance version, etc.

Comment: The ticker is ^GSPC (i.e., S&P500) and there is no start and end day since I use the option period='max'. The computer without problem runs python 3.8.5 & yfinance 0.1.63 while the one with strange behavior python 3.9.7 & finance 0.1.70

Comment: Looking at the fact that with an older version everything seems to work fine; I'm inclined to belive that the bug is in the yfinance package rather than in the Yahoo finance api.

Comment: Thanks this confirms my suspect that it is a bug in the last yfinance version 0.1.70. In fact is it possible to do the same with yfinance 0.1.70?

Comment: Just for the sake of clarity, the mismatch in behavior is not between the "Defined" method and the "Max" method. The mismatch is between the "Max" method run with yfinance version 0.1.63 and version 0.1.70. As a confirmation if I run the same code with yfinance 0.1.70 (link below) I can replicate the bug: I see data starting only from 1950.    Link: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1eByqpQGTxKH7KmYUy-FDri6HyYALKzzw#scrollTo=JjIjciC94CX0

Comment: I think that this it is confirmation of the bugs lies in the new version of yfinance

Answer (score 0):

So in the end I have reinstalled yfinance version 0.1.63 instead of yfinance 0.1.70 and this has solved the error. Now the data history is correctly downloaded. So the only solution today is to downgrade to the last known working version, i.e. 0.1.63. Furthermore, I have reported the bug ([link](https://github.com/ranaroussi/yfinance/issues/980)) hoping that it will get fixed in the next release.

Luca